# Sum divided series

Tags: excel, sum, divide

I wanna ask you. I have value which I want divide and sum. I will give you example:
[Which I want series sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7EGi.jpg)

*A1* Value  5 *B1*

*A3* Count  4 *B3*

```
10,41666667 **B5**
```

=SUM(B1;B1/2;B1/3;B1/4)

I want when I change count value formula will calculate automaticaly as formula *"=SUM(B1;B1/2;B1/3;B1/4)"*
Count value continues up to n, formula should work even if count value 1000.

Please help. I hope so I could explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula

Formula used in cell **B5**

```
=SUM(B1/ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$B$3)))
```

Or you can use SUMPRODUCT Function as well, to avoid the `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`

Formula used in cell **D5**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D1/ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$D$3)))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(D1/ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$D$3)))

Comment: Yes does that serve the purpose ?

Comment: This formula worked =SUMPRODUCT(D1/ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$D$3))) 
thanks a lot